# Why on the VPS, uuid() is wrapped in a single quote?

Tags: mariadb

On my local machine, running `show create table Projects` returns this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Projects` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Guid` char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid(),
  `Name` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 DEFAULT NULL,
  `ImageGuid` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Slug` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Projects_Unique_Guid` (`Guid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Projects_Unique_Slug` (`Slug`),
  CONSTRAINT `Ck_Projects_NonEmptyGuid` CHECK (`Guid` <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
  CONSTRAINT `Ck_Projects_NonEmptyImageGuid` CHECK (`ImageGuid` <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

On the server however, it returns this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Projects` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Guid` char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'uuid()',
  `Name` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 DEFAULT NULL,
  `ImageGuid` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Slug` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'uuid()',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Projects_Unique_Guid` (`Guid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Projects_Unique_Slug` (`Slug`),
  CONSTRAINT `Ck_Projects_NonEmptyGuid` CHECK (`Guid` <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
  CONSTRAINT `Ck_Projects_NonEmptyImageGuid` CHECK (`ImageGuid` <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

As you can see, the only difference is that on the server the `uuid()` default is wrapped inside single quotes.

I can't find out the reason for this.

Why is it so and how can I reconfigure the server MariaDB to omit those single quotes?

**MariaDB version:**
MariaDB-1:10.6.5+maria~focal

Comment: *```.. `Slug` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'uuid()', ..```* - this is an error (or maybe misprint?) obviously. *how can I reconfigure the server MariaDB to omit those single quotes?* - you must execute according ALTER TABLE and set correct DEFAULT property for a column.

Comment: @Akina, I copied the output of `show create table` exactly. So it's what it is. And I have used the exact same script to create this table. In other words, the creation script was `uuid()` not `'uuid()'`. So there must be something related to the MariaDB instance.

Comment: Not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=756a9ca97e0f6e09ce8474eb162b851a *And I have used the exact same script to create this table. In other words, the creation script was uuid() not 'uuid()'. So there must be something related to the MariaDB instance.* I doubt strongly. What client do you use? Your issue looks like client/access library/framework issue.

Comment: That's why I can't find the problem. I'm using MariaDB's [official docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb). I use the same `docker-compose.yml` file for both development and production (except ports and passwords). I use Adminer as my web tool. But I tested `show create table` using C# and EF Core for MariaDB and it printed the same `'uuid()'`.

Comment: It's not interesting how you test the structure, only the way used for table creation should be investigated. Anycase this is not MariaDB issue - it never takes the initiative and does strictly what you was told.

Comment: I use `show create table` on the development machine to get the creation script. Then via **Adminer** I run the same exact script on the server. And we have a tool that scripts both the development and the production database for comparison, and I see that it changes `uuid()` to `'uuid()'`.

Comment: *I use `show create table` on the development machine to get the creation script.* - `show create table` shows final result, not the table creation process flow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136387/discussion-between-saeed-neamati-and-akina).